# How to remote access MySQL database locally from my computer(through Node.js app) without SSH?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I have a mysql server running on ec2 instance. I also have a Node.js app running locally from where I want to connect to my mysql database running on the ec2 instance. I'm using this following code to connect:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

const mysqlHost = config.host;
const mysqlUser = config.mysql_user;
const mysqlPassword = config.mysql_password;
const mysqlDb = config.mysql_db;
const mysqlPort = config.mysql_port;
/*
*
* Connection Options
*
* */
const options = {
    connectionLimit: config.connection_pool,
    host: mysqlHost,
    user: mysqlUser,
    password: mysqlPassword,
    database: mysqlDb,
    port: mysqlPort,
    multipleStatements: true,
    Promise: bluebird,
};

/*
*
* Pool
*
* */
logger.warn({ mysqlHost, mysqlDb }, 'Establishing MySQL Connection Pool');
const pool = mysql.createPool(options);
```

Now, it doesn't connect to the instance and gives this error:

> Unhandled rejection Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

I'm able to ssh into the mysql database through MySQL Workbench and it's working fine.
Also, I have set the Inbound rules to ALL traffic and from anywhere so there's no problem from AWS side.

I read a lot about it and here are my findings:
Edit the my.cnf file in mysql to bind it to the IP of the host computer (which I tried but not able to do it...throwing error everytime)
Here is my.cnf file

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Please someone help me out.

Comment: You want to make your mysql on ec2 instance public, or you want to access it through ssh tunnel?

Comment: I just want that I can connect to the mysql database through my node app running on my local computer and make changes into the db @Marcin

Comment: There are several ways of doing this. For example, you can make your ec2 instance public, or ssh tunnel, or VPN.

Comment: ec2 is already public. I read somewhere that MySQL in aws does not allow remote access so we have to somehow do it by editing my.cnf file so that MySQL allows remote access. @Marcin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So After a lot of research I finally figured this out!
So, the file **my.cnf** has contents as shown above and as said above I knew that somehow I had to use **bind-address** but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Turns out the file I was looking for was located here:

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d
```

Here, I edited the file as:

```
#skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

Since, mysql in aws instance doesn't allow remote access we gotta make the bind-address as shown below which means we can access it from anywhere. Also, we gotta comment the **skip-external-locking**.

That's it now without using ssh we can access the db with any user having correct privileges.
The user that I used was:

```
create user xyz identified by 'your-password'
```